# layout_width and layout_height

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way I can get around having to add the layout_width and layout_height parameters to my custom views? I know there are a few built in android views that you don't have to supply those attributes for.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a View's responsibility to decide whether or not it can/should provide these attributes. The parent ViewGroup dictates whether these attributes are mandatory or not. TableRow for instance makes them optional. Other layouts (LinearLayout, FrameLayout, etc.) require these params.

Comment: I hadn't thought about about it like that.  That being the case, how do I make the parent ViewGroup let the XML that "Hey, this guy doesn't need to show me these things."?

Answer (score 0):

When would you want to not use the height and width parameters?  I'm not sure but I think that would cause them to not even show up on the layout?

Look here for reference http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#layout-params

Comment: Much like the table, I don't need them because the parent view controls the children's layout parameters.  So the attributes I specify in the XML don't do anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

From the same [Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#layout-params) Dave has suggested.

> All view groups include a width and height (layout_width and
>   layout_height), and each view is required to define them. Many
>   LayoutParams also include optional margins and borders.

So it looks like, you *have to*.

Comment: How does the TableRow ViewGroup get around this?

Comment: @NicholasRoge I didnT know about the `ViewGroup` but it says it s an `abstract class` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) The classes that extend it, however, they implement `layout_height` and `layout_width`

Comment: @NicholasRoge But as i said, I didnT know about it. Can you define a ViewGroup and use it as a layout in an xml, for example ? I doubt it..

Comment: @NicholasRoge If you want the parent to arrange your CustomControl's width and height, why not use "match_parent"?

Answer (score 0):

If reducing common and redundant attributes is what you want, then you should try styling.

Developer guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Comment: It's not reduction I'm going for though.  It's removal.  There's no need at all for them to be there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes()` uses the strict `getLayoutDimension(int, String)`.
You need to extend whichever LayoutParams you need and override `setBaseAttributes`.
Inside you can either manually set width and height or use the more lenient `getLayoutDimension(int, int)`. Finally, you'll have to override in your layout class that you are using your own LayoutParams.

```
   @Override
   public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs) {
       return new LayoutParams(getContext(), attrs);
   }

   public static class LayoutParams extends FrameLayout.LayoutParams {
       public LayoutParams(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
       }

      @Override
      protected void setBaseAttributes(TypedArray a, int widthAttr, int heightAttr) {
         width = a.getLayoutDimension(widthAttr, WRAP_CONTENT);
         height = a.getLayoutDimension(heightAttr, WRAP_CONTENT);
      }
  }
```